# Why does the garbage collector take so much time to free memory after JSON.stringify apply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8

Here is an example of NodeJS code:

```
function toMB (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

console.log('Node memory usage:', toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

Array(10000000).join('qweqweqweqweqweqweq');

var sec = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Node memory usage:',  toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB (after', ++sec + ' sec.)');
}, 1000);
```

I have got the following results:

```
Node memory usage: 2.00 MB
Node memory usage: 183.31 MB (after 1 sec.)
Node memory usage: 183.32 MB (after 2 sec.)
Node memory usage: 183.32 MB (after 3 sec.)
...
Node memory usage: 183.83 MB (after 128 sec.)
Node memory usage: 183.83 MB (after 129 sec.)
Node memory usage: 183.83 MB (after 130 sec.)
Node memory usage: 2.13 MB (after 131 sec.)
Node memory usage: 2.21 MB (after 132 sec.)
Node memory usage: 2.21 MB (after 133 sec.)
```

Garbage collector free memory.
But if i use JSON.stringify with the same string length:

```
function toMB (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

console.log('Node memory usage:', toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

JSON.stringify(Array(10000000).join('qweqweqweqweqweqweq'));

var sec = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Node memory usage:',  toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB (after', ++sec + ' sec.)');
}, 1000);
```

I have got the following results:

```
Node memory usage: 2.00 MB
Node memory usage: 364.22 MB (after 1 sec.)
Node memory usage: 364.24 MB (after 2 sec.)
Node memory usage: 364.24 MB (after 3 sec.)
...
Node memory usage: 365.60 MB (after 482 sec.)
Node memory usage: 365.60 MB (after 483 sec.)
Node memory usage: 365.60 MB (after 484 sec.)
Node memory usage: 2.21 MB (after 485 sec.)
Node memory usage: 2.21 MB (after 486 sec.)
```

Why the time difference (485 vs 131) is so big?

Comment: have you done multiple test runs to see if this is reproducible? GCs are probably allocation-triggered, so it's not guaranteed to free memory immediately.

Comment: the8472 thanks for your reply. Yes i have done it. Result is the same.

Comment: well, i can't give you a definitive answer, but I simply assume that node's GC is allocation- and/or timer-triggered. So you just happen to have some floating garbage that gets collected later once one of those triggers fires.